# Permission denied with mv under apache

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi, mv

I have a bash cgi script called by apache which should move one file in /var/www/html to another in the same directory. I've set up the relevant permissions with selinux (e.g. chcon to httpd_sys_content_t) and I've changed the read/write permissions of the files/dirs and yet it still returns the following in the httpd error logs:

`mv: cannot move /var/www/html/file.txt to /var/www/html/file2.text: Permission denied`

Any ideas? There's nothing relevant in the audit log either...

Edit:

ls -l on /var/www/html/ shows

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache  157 May 16 15:50 file.txt
```

ls -l on /var/www/ shows

```
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root root  4096 May 17 12:28 html
```

Comment: Can you `ls -l /var/www/html/` and show the permissions for this folder?

Comment: Yep, have just included some extra info...

Comment: Ah, I needed to change the ownership of /var/www/html from root to apache. Thanks for the ls tip-off Nathan :]

Comment: Try adding `id >/tmp/my-id.txt` to see with what id the script is running. The html-directory may only written by root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file permissions for /var/www/html do not allow the apache user to manipulate the directory containing the file. You will need to allow apache write access to the /var/www/html directory.